# Customising plots in Labview

Tags: plot, labview, markers, customising

I have an XY Graph in Labview. I have no problems with its basic functionality.

I'd like to have a marker  on the plot (independent on the cursor) which would stay in a certain position that I could read out and display in the GUI. Also I want the user to be able to move the marker to a new position.

How can I implement this functionality?

I know the title isn't very well-chosen, so I'll be grateful for any edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited:

You can just add cursor.

Add a cursor, select the point style you like and click on **Allow dragging** as shown on the picture below.

You can modify or read the current position of the point using **Cursor Position** property of the XY Graph.

[image]

Comment: This solution doesn't allow the user to drag the marker to a different position.

Answer (score 1):

They’re called “annotations”; you can add an array of them via a property node.